# How to pass a value from mysql database inside input type=file using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to fetch the data from MySQL database and one of the field type is BLOB (image) and trying to put this value inside an input type = "file". I successfully managed to put the other values inside input type = "text" but not in type = file. Btw, these   are inside Bootstrap Modal.

Is there a way to pass this blob type inside  using Jquery?

```js
//open Edit Modal
$(".toggleEditModal").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#c_id").val($(this).data("id"));
  $("#c_name").val($(this).data("name"));
  $("#c_logo").val($(this).data("logo"));

  $("#editModal").modal("show");
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info toggleEditModal" data-id="<?php echo $rid; ?>" data-name="<?php echo company_name; ?>" data-logo="<?php echo $logo; ?>">Edit</a>

<div class="modal-body">
  <input type="text" id="c_id" class="form-control" />
  <input type="text" id="c_name" class="form-control" />
  <input type="file" id="c_logo" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**This is the sample output what I want to happen** when I open the Edit Modal, I want the filename to appear in input type = "file".

[image]

Comment: putting a file in the file type does not make any sense. you can show the user the file, but you cant populate the form input

Comment: Hi tim, thank you for the answer, but what I'm trying to do is to give the user an option whether to change the file (logo image) or leave it as is. I just want to show the user the name (filename) of the logo like company_name_logo.png ? I managed to output the mysql data inside input type = "text" but not in input type = "file". Please check my code above. Thank you

Comment: it's better to show an image instead of the file name

Comment: Yes It would be better, But I'm just trying to figure it out if it is possible? I added an image above. Thank you